# Android Room db one to many with List field

Tags: android, android-room, one-to-many

I need to define one to many relationship between 2 entities, my problem is that the entityColumn is a List<> field.

the one to many model:

```
public class CategoryAndOffer {
    @Embedded
    public Category category;
    @Relation(
            parentColumn = "mCategoryId",
            entityColumn = "mMobileCategoryList"
    )
    public List<Offer> offers;
}
```

mMobileCategoryList in Product is a field of type List< Integer>

how can I make this relationship work?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: how did you put a list as a field in the entity?! If it is a result of another query you should write your custom SQL query and room relation resolving can't help much.

Comment: Can you explain with more detail, what you are trying to do? Some mock concrete examples would be nice.

Comment: Hi, Offer contains an array (converted to string in db) of Category ids.
I am trying to make one to many. relationship in room db to be able to query all the categories with their products